# Whats the best timing to insert elements into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, dom-manipulation

I am wondering if there is method to get the best timing to insert new HTML elements into the DOM.

Since we have `window.requestAnimationFrame()`, which is for animations, maybe we also have a `window.requestDOMManipulationFrame()` for DOM manipulations.

Comment: Animations need to be fluid, hence the `requestAnimationFrame` system. You hardly need to worry about such things for DOM elements…?!

Comment: Not really no, as the timing of when DOM nodes are inserted doesn't really matter. Do you have a specific issue or use case?

Comment: No specific use case or issue. I am just doing minor optimizations on an existing project where we have these DOM insertions, and wondered if there was a "best way" to do the insertion.